# React module not loading using require

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling to get my React module loaded. My error occurs within my App function, where it doesn't recognize the '<' character as commented in the code below.

I've tried using `import` rather than `require` but then `type: module` in my package.json causes problems with my other modules (namely AdminJS). So I'm hoping I can successfully do this with `requires`.

Any idea why my Reach module isn't loading, if that is indeed the problem? If it helps, I'm trying to implement this combination lock module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/combination-lock-react)

Thanks in advance.

game.js

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const CombinationLock = require('combination-lock-react');
```

```
    function App() {
        return (
            <div className="app"> // it fails at the "<" on this line: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
                <
                // stuff here
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "express-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "author": "Overlord",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@adminjs/express": "^4.1.0",
    "@adminjs/mongoose": "^2.0.2",
    "adminjs": "^5.6.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "combination-lock-react": "^1.0.3",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-formidable": "^1.2.0",
    "express-pjax": "^0.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "mongo": "^0.1.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.4.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "pjax": "^0.2.8",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.5",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Is there something keeping you from using import instead of require? I see you're using 16.14.0 and this appears to be CRA.

Comment: When I use import, my AdminJS module throws errors. Perhaps I need to change AdminJS to `import` instead of `require` after I add "type": "module" to my package.json?

Comment: I guess it would apply to all of my other modules -- changing them over to `import`. Does that sound like what I need to do? This is my first go at this, so learning piece by piece.

Comment: I would highly suggest using the import module system over require. Anytime I see require I cringe a little. I don't know the full history but I believe `require` was the first iteration that the import system replaced.

Comment: Many thanks. I've converted to `import` across all of my modules. And of course it's surfaced new problems, namely that it cannot read my styles.css file extension now. `import "./public/css/styles.css";` is my code, and the error is: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".css" for C:\Users\steve\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\ThunderRoost\public\css\styles.css. I'm not well versed in this and can't find the solution easily, if you happen to know what to do to fix that. Thanks!

Comment: It's your build engine that would do that for you. I've used CRA and am currently using Vite and it has built in support for importing CSS. It appears to me that you're serving your React code from Express. The would mean express would need to know how to use CSS files which by default it doesn't. I would do one of two things: break your app up into a front end and a back end project (that should fix the CSS issue) OR look into Next.js https://youtu.be/Sklc_fQBmcs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247416/discussion-between-micky-and-sleepywakes).